# Calling jQuery from functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to call a jQuery from my `functions.php` in WordPress.

I'm using Divi Theme. When I add the script directly into Divi theme it works. But I want to add it to the `functions.php` form my child theme and this is where the problem start.

Functions.php

```
function coolbanner_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/coolbanner.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coolbanner_enqueue' );
```

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#cta-section').waypoint(function() {
        jQuery('#cta-section').toggleClass('animate-cta');
    }, {offset: '80%'});
});
```

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: It doesn't work and I can't figure out why

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: No error. Check test.bloomford.be

Comment: Did you try this?

 `function coolbanner_enqueue() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/coolbanner.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false);
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coolbanner_enqueue' );`

Comment: I cannot see `waypoint` js in your theme

Comment: You're solution works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function coolbanner_enqueue() {       
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/coolbanner.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coolbanner_enqueue' );
```

Comment: setting the version and the "in-footer" parameter doesn't help in this scenario since the waypoint library is undefined

Comment: @CraigWayne, magali said its working my solutions. why downvote?

Comment: Humbly apologize George, Reverting

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing the *jQuery Waypoint JS file*

Try enqueueing the jquery waypoint js file *BEFORE* using your custom script

```
function coolbanner_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-waypoint', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js', [ 'jquery' ] );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/coolbanner.js', array( 'jquery-waypoint' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coolbanner_enqueue' );
```

you can find the jquery waypoint github repo here...

https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints

Additionally the url I used below is from a cdn which you can find here:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/waypoints

if you feel more comfortable using the github's url

then just substitute the cdn url with the following...

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/master/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js`